# Deploying xbap in a full trust mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, xbap

I have xbap which needs to run on a full trust mode because my application needs to upload a file from the client machine to process. I have to provide a installation steps to install.
If i do it as a click one instillation, do i still get a security error? If so what is the best way to resolve it?

If i install it in remote server, I saw couple of options in internet like creating certificates and ask user to import this certificate. Other option is to ask the user to allow access to xbap applications which provides access to all xbap applications (not so good). what is best way?

It would be really great, if some could provide me the installation steps for both scenarios.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654392/how-do-i-run-a-full-trust-xbap-on-intranet/655121#655121).

Answer (score 0):

For mine i was follow guide to create cert via makecert.exe and make it as trusted publisher through IE then populate through clickonce trust problem will not come out again and notice that need to find a full trust hosting service provider like arvixe...

> When developing your ASP .NET
>   applications. You may run into some
>   dlls that require your application to
>   have full trust on the server. Many
>   web hosts do not allow your
>   applications to run in full trust. At
>   Arvixe, by leveraging the power of
>   Windows 2008, we will enable full
>   trust for your applications per
>   request.

[XBAP full trust deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100947/xbap-full-trust-deployment)
create your own certificate and deploy full trust.afterward, user install automatically for my case =D also can prompt to install or notify user click the button beside the address bar ^^