# Can I deploy XBAP without signing in full trust?

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

Can I deploy an XBAP without signing in full trust?

Answer (score 2):

By default your XBAP application will run in partial trust. Here you can [see the particular limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910.aspx) you get with this.

If you need a full trust application [you have one of the options described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654392/how-do-i-run-a-full-trust-xbap-on-intranet/655121#655121): either you provide a certificate with your app, or you configure an intranet CLR security policy.

UPDATE: [this article](http://scorbs.com/2007/01/10/xbap-trust-levels/) is also quite good.

Comment: This....This intranet CLR security policy ? Can it be configured on the domain user level.So that I can just tell the system administrator to set it and my application can run without the certificate,thus reducing my deployment scenario issues or facts.

Comment: AFAIK, that's hardly possible, at least we weren't be able to do that for our app easily. I'd like to know the exact answer as well.

Comment: Did you buy a certificate from an provider?

Comment: Partial trust is enough for us now. Next release of WPF is said to support full-trust elevation prompt for XBAP http://aspalliance.com/1906_WPF_4_VS_2010_and_NET_40_Series_.16

Comment: Partial trust is enough for us now ? Wow do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: Any this stuff you mention will be like released like in 6 months time,also talks about ClickOnce not browser url xbap ???

Comment: Who knows what they are cooking up and how the hell will it work in intranet corporate environment. sucks

Comment: No, I don't work for MS, I write an XBAP app for my current employer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. XBAP applications are restricted, and will run in a sandbox. There's no (straightforward) way of running an XBAP with full trust. The upside is that you will not have to sign it.

Comment: So you are telling me that I can just in visual studio 2008 not sign in and deploy it to IIS and give the full trust on client and wella it should run ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be [possible in .Net 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2009/11/06/new-wpf-features-full-trust-xbap-deployment.aspx) planning to be released in the first half of 2010. It is now in a beta phase, but it comes with a [go live license](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2009/10/19/going-live-with-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx) which allows you to 'go live' even with a beta version of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can have partial trust and full trust for Xbap. So, it's possible to deploy Xbap without full trust.

Comment: if your Xbap is partial trust then you dont need to singn in full trust.. There are two types of Xbap application