# Partial Trust in WPF 4

Tags: wpf, xbap, full-trust

I've started a new project in WPF 4 (.NET 4) and trying to see if I can run it in xbap mode. I need to run the application in Full Trust with the new mode made available in .NET 4 which asks the end user if the full trust application should be run.

I've set the "Security" mode to "Full Trust" application, and it builds just fine. When I run it, an exception is thrown and IE error message shows the following error.

Any ways around it??

```
Startup URI: T:\projects\Hightech Sources\PayRoll\PayRoll.Web\publish\PayRoll.Web.xbap
Application Identity: file:///T:/projects/Hightech%20Sources/PayRoll/PayRoll.Web/publish/PayRoll.Web.xbap#PayRoll.Web.xbap, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1d910f49755d2c97, processorArchitecture=msil/PayRoll.Web.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1d910f49755d2c97, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at PayRoll.Web.App.SelectAssemblies()
   at Caliburn.PresentationFramework.ApplicationModel.CaliburnApplication..ctor()
   at PayRoll.Web.App..ctor()
   at PayRoll.Web.App.Main()
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Windows.Interop.PresentationApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext actCtx)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)
   at System.AppDomain.nCreateInstance(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstanceHelper(AppDomainSetup adSetup)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Windows.Interop.PresentationApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext actCtx)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.ExecuteNewDomain()
   at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.Execute()
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.ExecuteDownloadedApplication()
   at System.Windows.Interop.DocObjHost.RunApplication(ApplicationRunner runner)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.XappLauncherApp_Exit(Object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl()
   at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission
```

Comment: A similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654392/how-do-i-run-a-full-trust-xbap-on-intranet

I didn't find any tutorial on WPF 4 about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to run the full trust self-signed xbap application is to either add the certificate to the client's machine (which may not be possible most of the times) or add the site's URL to list of trusted sites. I found latter the most convenient and application runs as if signed by a valid certificated issued by a trusted authority.

Note this is only possible in .NET 4.0 and won't work in prior versions of WPF/.NET